# Django treating lists differently than python? Output Mangled by HttpResponse?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

This might be a really obvious question. I'm using `return HttpResponse()` to get some idea about the variables that I'm debugging and essentially I'm building a query list, but when I append to a list in Django it behaves differently to that of Python and I don't know if this is a display issue.

Here in Django

```
QueryList = []
for item in spltfieldvalues:
    strpitem = item.strip('[],')
    queryitem = Q(fieldname+'__contains='+strpitem)
    QueryList.append(queryitem)
```

should give a comma separated list. However when I output using HttpResponse, I just get the following:

```
AND: MyAgePref__contains=u'_U18')(AND: MyAgePref__contains=u'_O76')
```

Where I would expect these two options to comma separated as in `[Q(A), Q(B)]`

Just trying this on appending strings, i.e.`QueryList.append('A')` gives `AA` on the output with no comma separation. But on a python console, it works fine and I get `['A','A']`. Is the `HttpResponse` mangling the output? Its odd because I use this to look at the `JSON` and all seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a list to `HttpResponse`, and a list is an iterator. When you do that, the iterator is seen as a sequence of strings to write to the browser, **not** as an object to turn into a string. From the [`HttpResponse()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators):

> Finally, you can pass HttpResponse an iterator rather than strings. If you use this technique, the iterator should return strings.

and, [further down the page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__):

> content should be an iterator or a string. If it’s an iterator, it should return strings, and those strings will be joined together to form the content of the response. If it is not an iterator or a string, it will be converted to a string when accessed.

Turn the list into a string *first* then publish it:

```
HttpResponse(str(QueryList))
```